# Why I can't update UILabel's localScale if I assign Vector3 directly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scaletransform, ngui

Why I can't update UILabel's localScale if I assign a Vector3 directly?

It works well if write it in the following way:

```
label.transform.localScale += new Vector3(3.5f, 3.5f, 3.5f);
```

But it doesn't work with following ways:

```
label.transform.localScale = new Vector3(4.5f, 4.5f, 4.5f);
```

or

```
label.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 4.5f;
```

Who can tell me why?

Comment: Is it UILabel from NGUI library you are talking about?

Comment: it is because label's original scale is one Vector3.one. So label.transform.localScale += new Vector3(3.5f, 3.5f, 3.5f) don't equal to label.transform.localScale = new Vector3(4.5f, 4.5f, 4.5f);